# How do I use Wikipedia's search option "deepcat"?

Tags: wikipedia, wikipedia-api

I'm developing a small application where an user can select a conceptual category (Physics, Biology, History, etc.) existing on Wikipedia to fetch random articles from, and I'm using the MediaWiki API in order to perform this. Unfortunately the majority of Wikipedia's articles are categorized under deeper subcategories, so once a generic category gets selected, it would be great for me to be able to fetch articles from its subcategories as well.
Enter `deepcat`. According to its [documentation](https://wikitech.wikimedia.org/wiki/Nova_Resource:Catgraph/Deepcat), `deepcat` is an option (gadget) users can enter in Wikipedia's search bar to fetch articles from a category and its subcategories, for example:
`deepcat:Mathematics`
should return articles from the category "Mathematics" and its subcategories. The problem is, [it doesn't seem to work](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?search=deepcat%3AMathematics&title=Special%3ASearch&profile=default&fulltext=1). The only message I receive back is:

> A warning has occurred while searching: Deep category query returned
>   too many categories

Wikipedia's search option and MediaWiki APIs both seem to return the same result, so it's not a matter of how my calls are written. Moreover, the search appears to be case sensitive: if I instead write `deepcat:mathematics` I get back the 9 articles currently classified under [Categoty:Mathematics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Mathematics), but no articles from its subcategories.
How do I fix this?

Comment: Possibly you could use PetScan. There also exists https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:RandomInCategory, but it has the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Public categories like (Physics, women, politicians...etc) have too much pages when your try to fetch it. That's why you see this error.

There is a tool called PetScan hosted by Wikimedia labs. You can easily type the category title, then select the depth you want to reach, and then it's done!. https://petscan.wmflabs.org/

Also, see how it works https://meta.m.wikimedia.org/wiki/PetScan/en

Comment: Looks good, but is there a way to use it with the MediaWiki API?

Comment: A direct way?. To my knowledge, No!. But you can run the original API of getting category members inside loop. For example if physics category have 3 sub-categories, then make another API request for each 3 sub-categories. That's mean you will need to run 4 API requests. That's why I prefer using PetScan.

Comment: Of course, better run a PetScan query to fetch some article ids followed by a MediaWiki call to fetch their content. Thank you!